# сортировка элементов на странице в алфавитном порядке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть:

```
<div id="menu">
 <div>
  <a href="#">
   <p class="menu-img"><img src="jam.gif" /></p>
   <p class="menu-txt">Ямайка<p>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#">
   <p class="menu-img"><img src="est.gif" /></p>
   <p class="menu-txt">Эстония<p>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#">
   <p class="menu-img"><img src="mal.gif" /></p>
   <p class="menu-txt">Мальдивы<p>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="sort"><a href="#">Сортировать по алфавиту</a></div>
</div>
```

Можно ли при нажатии на ссылку "Сортировать по алфавиту" отсортировать DIV элементы, находящиеся внутри div id="menu" в алфавитном порядке основанном на содержимом p class="menu-txt"

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Получить то, что будешь сортировать можно таким способом:
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-txt').innerHTML

А вот как вы их заменять между собой будете — надо отдельно додумать. Потому что сейчас все эти <div> безлики и никак их не отсортируешь.

Можно им, например, придать вида id='hello1'
брать их в массив DOM объектов и потом получая способом выше содержимое сортировать любой сортировкой=)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо. Решил с JQuery.

```
$("#sort").click(function () {
var mylist = $('#menu');
var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let select = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select');

$(select).change(function () {
    if (this.selectedIndex == 1) {
        let idCards = $(".card").map(function (i, card) {
            return $(card).attr("id");
        });
        let sortIdCards = idCards.get().sort();
        for (let i = 0; i < sortIdCards.length; i++) {
            $('.card-columns').append($('#' + sortIdCards[i]));
        }
    }
});
```